# How could I leave a small space between a name and time no matter the size on the name? (Pillow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Having some little problem with PIL. I'm trying to make a profile similar to discord's. This is fine but the problem I'm facing is I can't seem to figure own how to set the padding space from the user's name to the time.

---

Here's an image when text isn't changed [image: An image when text is the same]

Now when text is changed to make it longer [image: Longer text]

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageFont
import requests, io
# If testing this script, it's best to use the same fonts I used.
font = lambda size: ImageFont.truetype("Assets/capture/fonts/font.woff", size) # Downalod font: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7ccx8z1ptpiaw3/font.woff?dl=0
font2 = lambda size: ImageFont.truetype("Assets/capture/fonts/font2.woff", size) # https://www.dropbox.com/s/uagi0fz90cj30qc/font2.woff?dl=0

name, Time, Text = "John Doe Name", "Today at 12", "Lorem Ipsum"
# Open mask image
user = Image.open( io.BytesIO(requests.get("https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg").content) )
# Make it circle
mask = Image.open( io.BytesIO(requests.get("https://i.ibb.co/c8KcH2Y/mask.png").content )).convert('L')
user = ImageOps.fit( user, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5) ) 
user.putalpha(mask)

avatarImg = io.BytesIO()
user.save(avatarImg, format='PNG', quality=95)
user = Image.open(io.BytesIO(avatarImg.getvalue())).resize((72, 72))
user2 = user.convert("L")

back = Image.new('RGB', (900, 105), (54, 57, 63))
[back.paste(user, (20, 20), x) for x in [user2, user2, user2, user2, user2, user2, user2, user2, user2, user2]] # Did this so it can be pasted 10 times, You can change this line to "back.paste(user, (20, 20), user2)" to see before.

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(back)
draw.text((120, 15), name, "#dfdfdf", font=font2(25)) # Name
draw.text((120, 50), Text, (180, 181, 182), font=font(30)) # Message
draw.text((230, 20), Time, (114, 118, 125), font=font2(20)) # Time (This is the line with the problem)

back.save("./avatarDone.png", format='PNG', quality=95)
```

The problem is on the line that says `draw.text((230, 20), Time, (114, 118, 125), font=font2(20))`, 230 is the horizontal padding space from the name to time, I tried to changing `230` to `len(name)+5` hoping the space will be the amount of letters in the name + 5 more spaces but doesn't look like PIL goes with spaces (I'm thinking it goes with pixels) as the spaces are way less than actual spaces

Comment: You need to make the placement of the `time` text dynamic, based on the length of the `name` text. It looks like you are giving the name field a constant 110 pixels (120 - 230) of space.

Comment: Use `ImageDraw.textsize()` to measure the name string and determine its width (and height), then you can figure out where it'll end. Given that you can determine a starting position for the time string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the placement dynamic by modifying last `draw.text()` to be like so:

```
threshold = 20 #20px between the last character of name and first character of Time
name_size = draw.textsize(name, font=font2(25))
draw.text((120+name_size[0]+threshold, 20), Time, (114, 118, 125), font=font2(20))
```

After that, you don't need to change anything but the name. Here is a screen shot when the name is just `John Doe`:

[image]

Here is another one when the name is `John Doe Name`:

[image]

And here is another one when the name is `John Doe Name John Doe Name`:

[image]

**Note:** You should know that when you change the font of `name`, it will affect the `name_size`. So, you need to change it as well while getting `name_size`